# No AJAX call with live()-binded click

Tags: jquery

Im trying to use AJAX inside a live()-function but it does not work. Any suggestions?
The ajax call is working (see example 1) and the click is registred (see alertbox 1, example 2) but when calling it inside that live()-click, the AJAX call does not return any data

```
//Ajax function which gets called
function ajaxFunc(){
   $.get("test.php", function(data){
     alert(data);    //Says "hello nerd!" from PHP script
   });
}

//Example 1. Works fine.
$('#button').click(function(){
   ajaxFunc();  //Alerts "hello nerd!"
});

//Example 2. Does not work
$('.category_item').live('click', function(){    
    alert("Testing. Yes, click works)";       //Alertbox 1, 
    ajaxFunc(); //Alerts a empty alertbox       Alertbox 2
});
```

Comment: you are using a relative uri for your ajax call, the page you use the example is in the same directory ?

Comment: is this alert getting fired alert("Testing. Yes, click works)";

Comment: +1 for "hello nerd!". Also, interesting question.

Comment: i don't see any problem in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason that the quoted code wouldn't work if, as you say, you're seeing the "Testing. Yes, click works" alert. Note that your quoted code has a syntax error there, you have the `"` and `)` reversed; I assume that was an artifact of posting the question, because you said it *did* work.

If you fix that, it works fine: http://jsbin.com/uvuyi4

And that makes sense; nothing in `ajaxFunc` relies on anything from the context in which it's called, so it doesn't matter where it's called from.

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error:

```
alert("Testing. Yes, click works)";
```

should be:

```
alert("Testing. Yes, click works");
```

Comment: Thanx for replay but it doesnt affect my problem

Comment: @lars: Well, if the code is a direct quote, it would -- the call to `ajaxFunc` wouldn't happen because the interpreter will bail on the bad `alert` line. But I'm guessing you didn't have that alert there until you were already having the problem, and that you introduced the syntax error when posting your question...